# Show that (x-1)^2 is a factor of.......?

Tags: polynomials, roots, common-root

**Show that $(x-1)^2$ is a factor of $x^n-nx+n-1$**

Here's my approach:-
Letting $P(x)=x^n-nx+n-1$
I tried putting $P(1)=0$ but it would only prove for $,(x-1)$

Here's what I can think of,
$x^n-1-nx+n=(x^n-1)-(nx-n)=(x-1)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+x^{n-3}................+x+1)-n(x-1)$

Because $x^n-y^n=(x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+x^{n-3}y^{n+1}................+xy^{n-2}+y^{n-1})$

$=(x-1)[x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+x^{n-3}................+x+1-n]$

But I am not able to proceed any further neither I am able to get $(x-1)^2$ as common factor.

Comment: Putting $P(1) = 0$ got you that $(x-1)$ is a factor; if you now look at $P'(1) = 0$, you'll get that it's a factor of the derivative, which will get you where you need to go.

Comment: Show that $P'(x)$ also has a zero at $x=1$.

Comment: John Hughes it may work but I'm not getting it, Please elaborate a little. Why it being a factor of the derivative prove (x-1)^2 to be a factor of P(x)?

Comment: @UnnayanUpadhyay One can write any polynomial as $f(x)=a+b(x-1)+(x-1)^2g(x)$; now consider what $f(1)$ and $f'(1)$ are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P(x)=x^n-nx+n-1=(x^n-1)-(nx-n)$

$=(x^n-1)-n(x-1)=(x-1)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+...+x+1-n)$

$P(1)=((1)-1)((1)^{n-1}+(1)^{n-2}+...+(1)+1-n)=(0)(0)$

Comment: Oh, thanku. That is, we first take (x-1) as common and then put P(1) which shows that (x-1) is again a factor of the polynomial. So in the end we got two (x-2) factors which multiply to become (x-2)^2. Is this is what you have proven?

Comment: @UnnayanUpadhyay Two (x-1) factors, but yeah, you've got the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, experimenting with a few cases suggests the factorization
$$x^n-nx+n-1=(x-1)^2(x^{n-2}+2x^{n-3}+3x^{n-4}+\cdots +(n-2)x+(n-1))$$
which is readily verified.

Comment: Hey, Can you prove it please?

Comment: @UnnayanUpadhyay I'm sure lhf can. But now that you have the formula, can **you** prove it?

Comment: Yet another FAQ dupe.

Comment: Ok I'll try. And by the way I didn't meant to challenge him. The proof would have been more helpful